# Express Request body/query are empty

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, routes, http-post

I've read nearly every post I could find on this, and they did not fix my issue.

I have:

```
var cors = require('./cors.js');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

- I have CORS set up to allow requests.
- I'm sending my POST requests with `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Yet my route's request object is still empty.

It works fine if I send my data via parameters, but I would really prefer to use body.

Request code:

```
data = {
    "url": "./text file name.txt",
    "body": "test content"
};

$.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'url': 'http://localhost:3000/save',
    'body': JSON.stringify(data),
    'success': function( response ){
        console.log( 'SUCCESS >>> ', response);
    },
    'error': function(error){
        console.log( 'ERROR >>> ', error.responseText );
    }
});
```

Route:

```
app.post('/save', function(request, response) {
    console.log( 'Save Req >> ', request.url, request.body, request.query );
    // outputs: "Save Req >>  /save {} {}"
});
```

CORS: (cors.js)

```
module.exports = function() {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
  };
}
```

Comment: Headers should be set via the `headers` property, did you try that (e.g. `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }`)?

Comment: @mscdex - When I try that, it changes my request type to OPTIONS, despite setting it to POST. I then get an HTTP error.

Comment: You have to set your server up to handle CORS requests because I believe `localhost` is a special case (assuming your client-side script is served over the same host and port -- `localhost:3000`). Also, not all browsers may have the same behavior when it comes to submitting requests to `localhost`.

Comment: @mscdex - Sorry, I forgot to include that I do have CORS set up. Will add to post.

Comment: That just shows you `require()`ing the `cors` module, not if/how you're actually using it.

Comment: @mscdex - Updated. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: But *where* are you actually *using* the function exported by cors.js? Also, have you tried simply calling `res.end()` instead of `next()` in your CORS function when `req.method === 'OPTIONS'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to $.ajax data in body is being passed in `data`, not in `body`. Like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: This worked, but it's confusing; why does the request use 'data' as the key, but then the route accesses it via the 'request.body' key?